# CAN bus sensors

Tags: sensor, can

I want to replace a broken CAN bus sensor with a new one. How can I do it?

I don't have node ID of the broken sensor.

Is there a way I can find the node ID of previous sensor?

It's an angle sensor (AMU-CBO)

Thanks

Comment: making an assumption that some program is reading it ... examine the program

Comment: This is some highly specific application you are talking about. How to use one particular application that happens to have a CAN bus would be off-topic here.